# How do I put today's date in the first column of every row in Python's dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

I use the following code to move data from one Excel file to another:

```
import pandas as pd
inventory=pd.read_excel('Original_File.xlsx', skiprows=3)
inventory.to_excel('New_File.xlsx', index=False)
```

How do I place today's date in the first column of every row that contains data in New_File.xlsx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
inventory=pd.read_excel('Original_File.xlsx', skiprows=3)
inventory.insert(0, 'today_date', datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
inventory.to_excel('New_File.xlsx', index=False)
```